# How to include all php files in Nginx's rewrite rule?

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

What I'm trying to do is allow any of the following to work:

> site.mydomain.com/{id}?args (defaults to index.php)
>
> site.mydomain.com/{id}/{any file if exists}?args (could be calendar.php, upload.php, etc. If not it will 404)

What I have in my Nginx config is the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    server_name site.mydomain.com;

    root /var/www/php/my_site/public;

    index index.php;

    access_log /var/log/sites/my_site.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/sites/my_site.error.log error;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1$is_args$args last;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php.inc;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is my php.inc that I'm including in my location so it will actually execute the php versus downloading it:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

When I go to `site.mydomain.com/{id}` it works

If I append `/index.php` on the end of it, I get a 404 error, or any other php file for that matter.

I need the index.php (and other files) due to backwards compatibility for older applications.

I've tried several configuration options around SO and googling, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm fairly new to nginx so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Here is my directory structure if it helps:

```
/var/www/php/my_site
    /application
    /library
    /public
        /static
            /styles
            /javascript
```

**EDIT**

I tried the suggested answer using:

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(/|/index.php)?$ /index.php?s=$1 break;
```

And it does the same thing. I've updated my question to be a bit more specific than before.

Comment: Is it only php files that have the id prefix? And do you want these rewritten with an `s=id` parameter?

Comment: The `{id}` is part of the URL. So: mysite.domain.com/12345/index.php, or mysite.domain.com/4567/index.php (or ajax.php, info.php). So yes, it would mean that the 12345 = s=12345 or s=4567

Comment: But not the static files? Or do you want it stripped from the URL of static files too, e.g. `/12345/base.css`

Comment: Correct, static files are handled just fine using the base url. So I don't need those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
location / {
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/([0-9]+)($|/) {
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.php$ /$2.php?s=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$2 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

The order of the last three `location` blocks is significant.

The `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php.inc;` has been moved out of the `location /` block and inserted at the end, so it provides a top level `location ~ \.php$` block rather than a nested location block. *I show the contents of the include file in my example above, but your `include` statement would work exactly the same.*

The `location ~ ^/([0-9]+)($|/)` block processes any URI that begins with an `/{id}` section. `rewrite` automatically appends the original query string to the rewritten URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

You should include the `try_files` statement in your `location ~ \.php$` block to avoid sending [uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) and return a 404 response if the PHP file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did as you suggested and still get the 404 when going to index.php. It works though without it. Another though, I do have a few more php pages that will need to be accessible. Is there a way to do a catch all php? The whole idea here is to be able to read in the {id} param and pass it in my main controller.php to identify the user

Comment: Any other info you could potentially provide? The `(/|index.php)` didn't work. I've also updated my question to include all php files versus just index.php. I appreciate the help you've already given.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm going to try this in the morning. I greatly appreciate your responses so far

Comment: This worked like a charm!! Thank you so much, you saved me a ton of head on desk banging